# I can't add WCF reference to windows mobile project?

Tags: c#, wcf, visual-studio-2008, compact-framework, windows-mobile-5.0

I create a smart-phone project(Windows mobile pocket pc 5.0 sdk and CF3.5) and the WCF created on the same solution in visual studio 2008.When i choose "add web reference" and then choose " Web services in this solution" i get this error
**None - No Web services were found in the current solution.**
If i put its URL and click Go I get this error
**This program cannot display the web page.**
Can any one help me in this problem??

**I think the problem in the URL i put it on the web reference.I replace the "localhost" with my computer IP but also doesn't work???**

Answer (score 0):

Try adding a [Service Reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb386382.aspx) instead of a Web Service Reference. Web References are for  the old XML Web Services functionality not for most WCF services.

EDIT:
This question is for Windows Mobile Pocket PC 5.0 which apparently doesn't support WCF service references but this [blog post shows how to add a WCF service reference](http://d3coder.wordpress.com/2010/08/20/consuming-a-wcf-service-from-a-windows-mobile-6-application/) to Windows Mobile 6.0 using Web References. It outlines the basic process which should work for Windows Mobile 5.0 projects.

Comment: There is no option in visual studio 2008 smart device projects called "Add service reference".

Comment: Seems strange because VS 2008 certainly supports [adding Service References](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb386382(v=vs.90).aspx). However, if the Windows Mobile projects don't offer that option and you want to use WCF services you'll need to configure the service to support basicHttpBinding which is compatible with the the old XML Web Services functionality.

Comment: How can i do this??
By changing the value of "binding" to be equal "basicHttpBinding"in App.config file of the WCF.Is this right??

Comment: The same error appears again.
Can any one help me this problem??